# What JVM is running ant?

Tags: eclipse, ant, rad

i an running RAD 8.0.2 on a 64bit win7 machine.  I have an ant build script that I am trying to use the input task, but get the following error:

`java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load 32-bit SWT libraries on 64-bit JVM`

a quick google tells me that i need to tell the JVM to use 32bit...makes sense.  So going to Preferences / Java / Installed JREs; editing the default jvm to supply the VM arg -d32 doesn't do anything.

maybe ant is running in a different vm?  any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the JVM that is used by Ant by looking at the Run... COnfigurations in RAD/Eclipse

Can you run a 64 bit JVM in 32 bit mode? I understand that is applicable only to Solaris.

Refer to this:
[Forcing 64 bit jvm to 32 bit jvm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989540/forcing-64-bit-jvm-to-32-bit-jvm)

Is that the issue?

HTH

Manglu

Answer (score 0):

The first step would be to add a 32-bit JRE to the workbench, by using the "Installed JRE" panel in the configuration.

Next, edit your Ant launcher. This is found in the "External Tools" menu - just expand "Ant builds" and you should see the launcher there. Go to the JRE tab and ensure that the build file is being run with an alternate JRE - the JRE that you defined in the previous step.