# How to connect to Access .mdb database from 64-bit Java?

Tags: java, ms-access

Hi I have the below code to connect to MS Access database on Windows 7 OS. I have changed the Data Source short cut to point to 64bit odbc then 32 bit. But still getting the error as

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:6956)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7113)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLDriverConnect(JdbcOdbc.java:3072)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.initialize(JdbcOdbcConnection.java:323)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.connect(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:174)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:579)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:221)
    at TestDBConnection.main(TestDBConnection.java:21)
```

And my code is :

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class TestDBConnection {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try
        {
            System.out.println("filename");
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            String database = 
                      "jdbc:odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=C:\\Test\\Tests.mdb";
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(database, "", "");
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

How ever I have SQL Workbench tool through which I can connect to it but not through java code.

Please need help badly as I am struggling with this from past 3 hours searching on Google.

Comment: You're using the direct path to the `.mdb` file, not need to create any `DSN`. Try to add `*.accdb` also: *`JDBC:ODBC:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ=DBQ=C:\\Test\\Tests.mdb`*

Answer (score 8):

If your Java app is running in a 64-bit Java Virtual Machine (JVM) then `DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}` is not going to work because there is no 64-bit version of the Jet database engine. You can...

- Download and install the 64-bit version of the Microsoft Access Database Engine from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=13255), and then use `DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}` in your code.

... or ...

- Run your Java app in a 32-bit JVM and continue to use the existing `DRIVER=` string. The related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5906532/2144390) might prove helpful if you choose this option.

... or ...

- Use the [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) JDBC driver for Access databases. It is a free, open-source, pure Java implementation so it works on both 32-bit and 64-bit systems, both Windows and non-Windows. It also works with Java 8 (which has dropped the JDBC-ODBC Bridge). For more details, see:

[Manipulating an Access database from Java without ODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21955256/2144390)

Comment: If anyone is having this error using 64 bit JVM try adding "*.accdb" to your "DRIVER=..." string. Worked for me.

Comment: Reverting to 32-bit saddened me, but having my script exporting correctly made me happy again. (I live a simple life)

Answer (score 1):

You can install the 64 ODBC drivers for Access available from Microsoft

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Comment: I was restricted from this route due to 32-bit office programs being installed.

Comment: Do you mean, when office 32bit is installed, you can't also install the 64bit odbc drivers on the same system?

Comment: I think so as per the error message I received. Windows recommended I uninstall my 32-bit programs.

Answer (score 0):

1) you will have to configure System dsn (Driver Microsoft Access Driver(*.mdb,*.accdb)) 
2) link .mdb database in above configuration
and write below code.

```
 Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
 String database = "jdbc:odbc:systemdsnname";
 Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(database, "", "");
```