# Using Vaadin with a database created in Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access, vaadin

I'm trying to develop a simple web application to run on my company's internal network. I've recently taught mysef the fundamentals of Vaadin and Microsoft Access. I've gotten Vaadin to access a simple MySQL database without any problems. I've also created the real database in Access. My question is how do I get the two to work together? Is there a driver I can use to access the .accdb database itself, or is there a format I can convert to that is compatible with Vaadin but can also still be administered with Access?

Answer (score 2):

Using vaadin with a database is "simply" making the right choice for the JDBC drivers.

For MS Access you can either go via the ODBC Bridge, or purchase a professional JDBC driver.

When you go the ODBC bridge way, you then have to make sure that the server java vm matches the odbc version. Either both 32 Bit or both 64 Bit.

Look here: [How to connect to Access .mdb database from 64-bit Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19334723/how-to-connect-to-ms-access-database/19668884#19668884)

In the meantime MS has provided 64 Bit ODBC drivers for MS Access too. But the platform needs to be Microsoft Windows.

Please be aware, that MS Access is a bit tricky when using in multiuser mode. If it's a real project, then you should consider migrating it to a real database.